# Django foreign keys in a template

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-templates, django-nonrel

I'm using django-nonrel with Google App Engine, and I've got a model object in django which is storing a list of foreign keys. I'm sending this object to a django template, and I want the template to be able to access the objects referenced by my original object. However, in the django template, the foreign keys are just represented as unicode numbers, so it seems I can't access the items directly from the django template.

Is there a way I can send my original object to the django template and easily access the objects represented in the foreign key fields? I know in normal django it would probably be best practice to use the manytomany field, however django-norel doesn't support this.

Thanks for any suggestions you can provide!

Comment: sorry, i mean unicode string with a number in it. (e.g. u'3')

Comment: A 'decimal string', then. Are they key names, or IDs?

Comment: You can try using select_related query and accessing the foreign keys with something like object__foreignKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably resolve the original objects before sending it to the template - by iterating over the list of keys, getting the relevant objects, and adding them to an new list) Then you can pass that new list in a separate attribute on the object.

This may be slow if you've got lots of items in your list(s).